# Using MVC style, where is the best place to call my query functions?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller

I am wondering about best practices here.

MVC (Model - View - Controller) patterns involve separating components of your program that model the data, manipulate those models, and display those results to the user (usually through the UI) in some way.

What about a function that takes the model data and inserts it into a database? For example I have an object called a GameBoard, and I also want the ability to insert the state of this board into the SQL database for storage / historical purposes. I have a class that holds all my query functions. I am not asking where to store the query calls themselves -- again those are all encapsulated in one class.

But where would I call these functions *from*? Would this sort of functionality make the most sense to make it as a method of GameBoard? Or should it be part of the controller classes?

Comment: I think that should be the controller the one that initializes de GameBoard and invokes the method for storing it in the DB using your class with the queries. GameBoard could have a method for getting its state, invoked by controller when it needs to register board status in the DB.

Comment: @RubioRic That is also what I am thinking, but it is helpful to hear it from others to see if I am on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ideal world, class that performs GameBoard state persistence should listen to game events:

1. UI button is clicked
2. Controller invokes some Model method (increment counter by one)
3. Model updates its internal state
4. Model notifies all listeners, that are interested in state change events
5. Controller receives event and updates the UI
6. DB Component receives event and saves GameBoard state to database

---

When user clicks UI button to update view with database data:

1. UI button is clicked
2. Controller loads the data and invokes model update method

next 3-4-5 steps are the same

Comment: If user click the UI button for getting some data from database. Then can you put the steps for this? I think like this user click the button, controller invokes the business logic(business layer). Model listen to the changes in the business logic model and update the Model in MVC(presentation layer)

Answer (score 1):

> But where would I call these functions from?

In the controller. Usually the controller has dependencies to model objects for input and outout. E.g.

[image]

Depending on your architecture you might introduce an application service below the controller.

Details at https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2013/07/20/the-mvc-pattern-implemented-with-java-swing/

Answer (score 0):

Following are the points for MVC.

1. Make a strong separation between presentation (view & controller)
   and domain (model).
2. Divide GUI widgets into a controller (for reacting to user stimulus)
   and view (for displaying the state of the model).
3. Controller and view should (mostly) not communicate directly but
   through the model- [Observer Synchronization](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/MediatedSynchronization.html).

> where would I call these functions from?

You should call these functions from your [domain model](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html) (model).

Further Reading [martin fowler](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html#ModelViewController)